# NPE when initializing an object in onSizeCanged()

Tags: java, android

I have a class called `Table`, I declared an object of this class, and in`onSizeChanged()` I initialize it, but when I I try to refer to it inside `onDraw()`, the app crashes and a `NPE` is thrown

***Code***:

```
public class GameView extends View {
private Table mTable;
....
....
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

canvas.drawText("Table_Height: "+mTable.getTableHeight(), 10, 15*  
(cardArraySize_Height), textPaint);
....
....
....
}
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
setupMainTable(mTable);
...
...
...
}

private void setupMainTable(Table table) {

table = new Table(10,
  ((screenHeight/2)-(2*cardHeight)),
  (screenWidth-10),
  ((screenHeight/2)+(2*cardHeight)));
```

}

Comment: whre is the mTable initialized?

Comment: @reidisaki i am passing the `mTable` object to the method `setupMainTable` as a parameter so it gets initialised inside that method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Java works by pass by value and not pass by reference**.So you need to do this:-

```
private void setupMainTable() {

this.mTable= new Table(10,
  ((screenHeight/2)-(2*cardHeight)),
  (screenWidth-10),
  ((screenHeight/2)+(2*cardHeight)));
}
```

Comment: @Thank you. but i have a question, according to your answer, does it  mean that I can not pass `mTable` object to the function `setupTable` as a parameter?

Comment: @Elpharaoh You can definitely but as long as it is mutable Object,assigning a brand new Object reference does not change the Object which was pointed by that the caller reference.You can change an Object state but not the Object itself which is somewhere else in the heap.... :)

Comment: @Elpharaoh You may explicitly return the reference of your brand new Object and assign it where the method was called,so your setupMainTable has to have a return type as Table instead of void...protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
mTable = setupMainTable(mTable);

Comment: @ but if i passed an instant of the object `mTable` to the method`setupMainTable` i cant use `this`. for an example, `setupMainTable(Table mtable) {this.mtable //this would be wrong, is not it}`

Comment: @Elpharaoh yes.. you can always work on a mutable object reference..In your case,you are passing null reference which does not change when the method returns